# Searching for a word in a url error

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have one million odd urls and search terms in a text file with unique ID. I need to open the urls and search for the searchterms, if present represent as `1` else `0`.

Input file:

```
"ID" "URL","SearchTerm1","Searchterm2"
"1","www.google.com","a","b"
"2","www.yahoo.com","f","g"
"3","www.att.net","k"
"4" , "www.facebook.com","cs","ee"
```

Code Snippet:

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv 
import datetime 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open('txt.txt') as inputFile, open ('results.txt','w+') as proc_seqf:
        header = 'Id' + '\t' + 'URL' +  '\t'  
        for i in range(1,3):
            header += 'Found_Search' + str(i) +  '\t'
        header += '\n'
        proc_seqf.write(header)
        for line in inputFile:
            line=line.split(",")
            url = 'http://' + line[1]
            req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
            html_content = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)
            if line[2][0:1] == '"' and line[2][-1:] == '"':
                 line[2] = line[2][1:-1]
            matches = soup(text=re.compile(line[2]))
            #print soup(text=re.compile(line[2]))
            #print matches
            if len(matches) == 0 or line[2].isspace() == True:
                output_1 =0
            else:
                output_1 =1
            #print output_1
            #print line[2]
            if line[3][0:1] == '"' and line[3][-1:] == '"':
                 line[3] = line[3][1:-1]
            matches = soup(text=re.compile(line[3]))
            if len(matches) == 0 or line[3].isspace() == True:
                output_2 =0
            else:
                output_2 =1
            #print output_2
            #print line[3]

            proc_seqf.write("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(line[0],url,output_1, output_2))
```

output File:

```
ID,SearchTerm1,Searchterm2
1,0,1
2,1,0
3,0
4,1,1
```

Two issues with the code:

1. when I run around 200 urls at once it gives me `urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed error`.
2. Is there a way to search something which closely matches but not exact match?

Comment: why negative votes without stating the reason?

Comment: I suspect that the reasons are hinted at by the closure votes: too broad.  You've asked three questions in one posting, the second of which really belongs in Code Review rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you @Prune Made changes to the code.

Comment: Do you know what URL causes the urlopen failure? Is it always the same one?

Comment: it changes not a constant url.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Is there a way to search something which closely matches but not exact match?" -> can you clarify what you mean by "closely matches"?

Comment: OS is windows. For example search word is "Abc In." But in the website if we have just "Abc In" can I return back as 1 (i.e. match found)?

Comment: Is a trailling `.` the only possible kind of close match or are there others?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Mostly yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I run around 200 urls at once it gives me urlopen error [Errno 11004] 
>   getaddrinfo failed error.

This error message is telling you that the DNS lookup for the server hosting 
the url has failed.

This is a outside the control of your program, but you can decide how to 
handle the situation.

The simplest approach is to trap the error, log it and carry on:

```
try:
    html_content = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
except urllib2.URLError as ex:
    print 'Could not fetch {} because of {}, skipping.'.format(url, ex)
    # skip the rest of the loop
    continue
```

However, it's possible that the error is transient, and that the lookup will 
work if you try later; for example, perhaps the DNS server is configured to 
reject incoming requests if it receives too many in too short a space of time.
In this situation, you can write a function to retry after a delay:

```
import time

class FetchException(Exception):
    pass

def fetch_url(req, retries=5):
    for i in range(1, retries + 1):
        try:
            html_content = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        except urllib2.URLError as ex:
            print 'Could not fetch {} because of {}, skipping.'.format(url, ex)
            time.sleep(1 * i))
            continue
        else:
            return html_content
     # if we reach here then all lookups have failed
     raise FetchFailedException() 

# In your main code
try:
    html_content = fetch_url(req)
except FetchFailedException:
    print 'Could not fetch {} because of {}, skipping.'.format(url, ex)
    # skip the rest of the loop
    continue
```

> Is there a way to search something which closely matches but not exact match?

If you want to match a string with an optional trailing dot, use the `?` modifier.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

```
>>> s = 'Abc In'
>>> m = re.match(r'Abc In.', s)
>>> m is None
True

# Surround `.` with brackets so that `?` only applies to the `.`
>>> m = re.match(r'Abc In(.)?', s)
>>> m.group()
'Abc In'
>>> m = re.match(r'Abc In(.)?', 'Abc In.')
>>> m.group()
'Abc In.'
```

Notice the `r` character preceding the regex patterns.  This denotes a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation).  It's good practice to use raw strings in your regex patterns because they make it much easier to handle backslash (`\`) characters, which are very common in regexes.

So you could construct a regex to match optional trailing dots like this:

`matches = soup(text=re.compile(r'{}(.)?').format(line[2]))`

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb when I try to implement the first logic of having try and except I get could not fetch error for all urls?

Comment: can we chat I have couple of doubts thank you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132718/room-for-zack-and-snakecharmerb